# How can I show four images per row and rows can be of any no with php

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

Dear Friends I have a  Div of Images.

```
  <div class="img_team_container">    
      <div class="img_team_subcontain">
          <div class="img_team"><a href="#" class="btn_1" title="Dining"></a></div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

My question is that How can I show four images per row and rows can be of any no with php.

Comment: Im a bit confused by the question, you want a row on a page that has 4 images in it and there can be any number of rows? Where are you getting the information about these images from?

Comment: as a first step, try writing the HTML you want to create manually, for say two rows. this gives us a better idea of what you're trying to achieve and where your problem is. ideally, you might even start thinking about how to do this in php and make your question more concete!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a array `$images` of images:

```
<?php $i = 0; foreach($images as $image): ?>
  <?php if($i === 0): ?>
     <div class="row">
  <?php endif; ?>

      <?php echo sprintf('<img src="%s" />', $image['src']); ?>

  <?php if($i === 4): $i = 0; ?>
     </div>
  <?php else: $i++; endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

well i dont see an image tag in your code but use modulo arithmetics.

```
<?
$perRow=4;
for($i=0;$i < count($myimages); $i++) {
 echo '<img src="'.$myimages[$i].'"/>';
 if(($i+1)%$perRow === 0) {
  // we reched the end of the row, lets break
  echo '<br/>';
 }
}
?>
```